# Alert Xamarin.Ios Version Mismatch

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get this alert when I try to connect to a Mac.
Do I need to hit install?
Why is this warning displayed to me?
my visual studio mac and my visual studio 2019 windows and my xcode are the latest updates ... does anyone know what to do?

warning image : [MyWarning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcMbi.png)

Comment: Its a know issue, I had raised a issue on developer community for this. When it connects from Windows it requires different version you just have to install it, no alternative unless you switch to Preview channel on Mac

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/859531/pair-to-mac-always-shows-mismatch-versions-of-mono.html

Comment: Not coding question
Not coding question
Not coding question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can safely install. Sometimes the windows release and the mac release will have different versions. if you're going to be working from Windows then keeping it on the windows version is what you want to do.